# fixing race condition in tensorflow run

Tags: graph, tensorflow, race-condition, ambiguous

I would like to maintain a variable on the GPU, and perform some operations on that variable in place. The following snippet is a minimalish example of this.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default():

    i = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [4], name='i') 
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [4], name='y') 
    _x = tf.get_variable('x', [4], initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
    x = _x + tf.reduce_sum(tf.mul(_x,y))
    assign_op = tf.assign(_x, x).op
    permute_op = tf.assign(_x, tf.gather(_x, i))

    ii = np.array([1,2,3,0])
    yy = np.random.randn(4)

    s = tf.Session()
    s.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
    xxx0 = s.run(_x)
    s.run([permute_op, assign_op], feed_dict={i: ii, y: yy})
    xxx1 = s.run(_x)
    print('assigned then permuted', np.allclose((xxx0+np.dot(xxx0,yy))[ii], xxx1))
    print('permuted then assigned', np.allclose((xxx0[ii]+np.dot(xxx0[ii], yy)), xxx1))
```

The problem is that this program is ambiguous, in terms of the ordering of the assign_op and permute_op operations. Hence, one or the other of the final two print statements will be true, but which one that is varies randomly across multiple runs of the program. I could break this into two steps, the first running the permute_op and the second running the assign_op, but it seems this will be less efficient.

Is there an efficient way of breaking the race condition, and making the results predictable?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to order the two assignments is to use the *result* of the first assignment as the variable input to the second one. This creates a data dependency between the assignments, which gives them a deterministic order. For example:

```
assigned = tf.assign(_x, x)
permuted = tf.assign(assigned, tf.gather(assigned, i))

sess.run(permuted.op)  # Runs both assignments.
```

Note that I reversed the order of the permutation and assignment operations from what you said in your question, because doing the permutation first and then updating still has a race. Even if this isn't the semantics you wanted, the principle should hopefully be clear.

An alternative approach is to use `with tf.control_dependencies(ops):` blocks, where `ops` is a list of operations (such as assignments) that must run *before* the operations in the `with` block. This is slightly trickier to use, because you have to be careful about *reading* the updated value of a variable. (Like a non-volatile variable in C, the read may be cached.) The typical idiom to force a read is to use `tf.identity(var.ref())`, so the example would look something like:

```
assign_op = tf.assign(_x, x).op

with tf.control_dependencies([assign_op]):
    # Read updated value of `_x` after `assign_op`.
    new_perm = tf.gather(tf.identity(_x.ref()), i) 
    permute_op = tf.assign(_x, new_perm).op

sess.run(permute_op)  # Runs both assignments.
```